# kdb voolkup. get value from table that is mapped to smallest val larger than x

Tags: kdb, q-lang

Assuming I have a dict

```
d:flip(100 200 400 800 1600; 1 3 4 6 10)
```

how can I create a lookup function that returns the value of the smallest key that is larger than x? Given a table

```
tbl:flip `sym`val!(`a`b`c`d; 50 280 1200 1800)
```

I would like to do something like

```
{[x] : update new:fun[x[`val]] from x} each tbl
```

to end up at a table like this

```
tbl:flip `sym`val`new!(`a`b`c`d; 50 280 1200 1800; 1 4 10 0N)

sym val new
a   50    1
b   280   4
c   1200  10
d   1800
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will want to use [`binr`](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/search/#bin-binr) to return the next element greater than or equal to `x`. Note that you should use a sorted list for this to work correctly. For the examples above, converting `d` to a dictionary with `d:(!). flip d` I came up with:

```
q)k:asc key d
q)d k k binr tbl`val
1 4 10 0N
q)update new:d k k binr val from tbl
sym val  new
------------
a   50   1
b   280  4
c   1200 10
d   1800
```

Where you get the dictionary keys to use with: `` k k binr tbl`val ``.

Edit: if the value in the table needs to be mapped to a value greater than `x` but not equal to, you could try:

```
q)show tbl:update val:100 from tbl where i=0
sym val
--------
a   100
b   280
c   1200
d   1800
q)update new:d k (k-1) binr val from tbl
sym val  new
------------
a   100  3
b   280  4
c   1200 10
d   1800
```

Comment: when I sort the dictionary, k:asc key d I get a type error

Comment: The variable `d` you provided is not currently a dictionary, just a list of lists. I converted it by doing: ```d:(!). flip d```.

Comment: perfect. that worked exactly as I hoped for. thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

stepped dictionaries may help
http://code.kx.com/q/cookbook/temporal-data/#stepped-attribute

```
q)d:`s#-0W 100 200 400 800 1600!1 3 4 6 10 0N
q)d 50 280 1200 1800
1 4 10 0N
```